# Shell Loop Until issues

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
#!/bin/bash
chk_qos=Yes

down_report=180
up_report=350

if [ "$chk_qos" = "Yes" ];
then

    echo "Measure The Bandwidth"

until [ $down_report -ge 200 ] && [ $up_report -ge 200 ];

do
    echo "Starting QoS, Please Wait..."
    sleep 5

done

else
    echo "Service Not Enabled..."
fi
```

I want if both variable values are greater than or equal to 200 then done else re-try until the value is met, now the issue is when the value matches I mean both variable value greater than or equal 200 then code is working & when not met it's trying also that is fine, but when is update during trying it's not stopping & keep trying even values match, please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: Why not use `while [ "$down_report" -le '200' ] || [ "$up_report" -le '200' ]; do ... done` ??  (note the edit with `||` and `-le`)

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Please add the code which modifies the loop invariants 'down_report' and 'up_report'. Seems like they are not updated as intended.

Comment: You need to modify the variables yourself if you want to exit the loop once you enter it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something in the loop that changes the condition. For example,

```
until [ $down_report -ge 200 ] && [ $up_report -ge 200 ];

do
    echo "Starting QoS, Please Wait..."
    sleep 5
    down_report=$(( down_report + 1))
    up_report=$(( up_report + 1 ))
done
```

This is just an example, but it illustrates the point that if either variable is less than 200, you need to do something in the body of the loop to increase at least one of them, or the loop condition (starting out false) will *always* be false. Most importantly, nothing *outside* your script will modify those variables, if that is what you are expecting.

Answer (score -1):

If your requirement is to stop if greater than or equal to 200, else retry then the code should be as below

```
    until [ $down_report -lt 200 ] && [ $up_report -lt 200 ];
 do
 echo "Starting QoS, Please Wait..." 
sleep 5 
done
```

The changes made is -lt

Comment: Given the initial values, this is never true, and there's no need for the loop. The problem is that nothing modifies the two variables, making it impossible for an unmet condition to ever *be* met.

Comment: This is also wrong. The users wants to loop *until* the variables both exceed 200. Changing to `-lt` would require `while ... || ...`.